# Oracle cilent and Perl installation on Centos

Tags: oracle, perl, oracle11g, installation

I'm not abble to install  DBD-Oracle.

I have installed the oracle client following these steps:

1. I have downloaded the instant Client ZIP file.
2. Unziped the packages into  directory  `"/opt/oracle/product/instantclient_12_1".`
3. Created the appropriate `libclntsh.so` and `libocci.so` links :

   ```
   cd /opt/oracle/product/instantclient_12_1
   ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so
   ln -s libocci.so.12.1 libocci.so
   ```
4. Setted the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory created in Step 2:

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/instantclient_12_1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ```

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns:

```
    /opt/oracle/product/instantclient_12_1:/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
```

Added this path to an ldconfig configuration `/etc/ld.so.conf` too.

```
ldconf -v returned
/opt/oracle/product/instantclient_12_1:
        libclntsh.so.12.1 -> libclntsh.so.12.1
        libociei.so -> libociei.so
        liboramysql12.so -> liboramysql12.so
        libocijdbc12.so -> libocijdbc12.so
        libmql1.so -> libmql1.so
        libnnz12.so -> libnnz12.so
        libclntshcore.so.12.1 -> libclntshcore.so.12.1
        libipc1.so -> libipc1.so
        libons.so -> libons.so
        libocci.so.12.1 -> libocci.so.12.1
```

5. Updated `PATH` environment variable:

   ```
   export PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1:$PATH
   ```

Now I'm trying to install DBD-Oracle, following these seps

```
  tar xfvz DBD-Oracle.tar.gz
  cd DBD-Oracle
  perl Makefile.PL
  make
  make install
```

Anyhow getting this error:

```
Trying to find an ORACLE_HOME
Your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var is set to ''

      The ORACLE_HOME environment variable is not set and I couldn't guess it.
      It must be set to hold the path to an Oracle installation directory
      on this machine (or a machine with a compatible architecture).
      See the appropriate README file for your OS for more information.
      ABORTED!
```

But these vars are not empty:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/oracle/product/instantclient_12_1:/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
 echo $ORACLE_HOME
/opt/oracle/product/instantclient_12_1/
```

Comment: Does it help if you retry in a brand new terminal window? (perhaps the variables haven't 'refreshed' in the current terminal)

Comment: Not really that but thank you! It seems, that I have some problems with variables while using sudo. Will come back to it on mon.

Comment: What are you doing with sudo?

Comment: You can use `sudo` to get a shell, but you can't use it multiple times: setting environment variables in a shell is not persistent and will not be present over multiple `sudo` calls.

Comment: Has your `Perl` been compiled 64-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compile `DBD::Oracle` on `AIX`, `CentOS`, `RedHat` and `Solaris` all the time.  I recommend that you make a script (especially if you are using `sudo` to compile these things).  Here's the script I use to set environment variables (some are extra and some are including for testing) and make the modules:

```
# These are usually pre-set in my environment:
export ORACLE_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/bin
export ORACLE_BASE=/usr/lib/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
export ORACLE_DOC=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/doc
export ORACLE_SID=Mydbsid
# My PATH include my /perl/bin directory

# My script starts here:
ulimit

/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install(qw(LWP HTTP::Date))'
/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install(qw(Bundle::CPAN))'
/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install(qw(Bundle::libnet Bundle::LWP Bundle::DBD::CSV Bundle::Net::LDAP))'

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
export TNS_ADMIN=my_tnsnames.ora_directory
export ORACLE_USERID=Username/Password@Mydbsid

/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install(qw(DBD::Oracle))'

export DBICTEST_ORA_DSN mydbsid
export DBICTEST_ORA_USER Username
export DBICTEST_ORA_PASS Password
export DBI_DRIVER Oracle
export DBI_DATABASE Mydbsid
export DBI_USERNAME Username
export DBI_PASSWORD Password

/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install(qw(Time::Piece Date::Simple DateTime::Format::Oracle Math::Base36 Class::DBI::Plugin::DeepAbstractSearch Class::Trigger DBIx::ContextualFetch DBIx::Class))'
/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install(qw(Task::Kensho))'
# It continues, but nothing more database-orientated appears later.
```

The latter environment variables are for testing other modules (such as `DBIx::Class`) that appear later in my build.

I've done this for Oracle 10 and 11, but not Oracle 12 (yet).

Comment: I was able to install RPMs 11.2. But getting this error: from DBD::Oracle WARNING: I will now try to guess how to build and link DBD::Oracle for you.
         This kind of guess work is very error prone and Oracle-version sensitive.
         It is possible that it won't be supported in future versions of DBD::Oracle.
         *PLEASE* notify dbi-users about exactly _why_ you had to build it this way.

Comment: Where should I put tnsnames.ora? in /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin?

Comment: If `ORACLE_HOME` is `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64` and `network/admin` exists, that would work.  When I install the Instant Client on my application servers though, `network/admin` does not exist and so I set `TNS_ADMIN` to my application's configuration file where I store `tnsnames.ora`.  Actually, on my application servers, I just worry about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (where my Oracle Instance Client libraries are) and `TNS_ADMIN` (where `tnsnames.ora` is) only.

Comment: And how about ORA_NLS33?

Comment: I've never specified `ORA_NLS33` (and so I guess it has always used the default value or it didn't matter for our application which is almost completely numeric rather than text).